# Microphone to capture eating sounds

Tags: microphone

I'm wondering if there's any good microphone that can capture sounds when chewing different foods?

I'm using a throat mic now, but it's quite uncomfortable. Is an in-ear microphone capable of recording the sounds? Or is there any recording setup that can capture chewing easily?

Comment: Do you interesting just chewing? Open or closed mouth?

Comment: I'm interested in identifying food type (such as chips, salads, steak or just water etc) from the sound. The mouth would be in the typical eating situation, so both open and closed. This would be collected in a closed room, so I could setup special microphones system as well (no need to be wearable).

Comment: I believe any condenser mic will work., but you will pick up not only chewing, but breathing too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A condenser mic on a stand, aimed slightly off-axis, on the table would be pretty close to ideal for this.

I recommend the condenser for increased sensitivity to capture some the subtler sounds.

If you wanted to be very fancy, a lavalier mic clipped to your shirt collar could capture some throat/swallowing noise as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're best choices would a shotgun or hypercardioid, like the MKH 416 or MKH 50, but if you get too close to a cardioid condenser you will experience problems with proximity effect boosting the low end. A good omnidirectional condenser microphone will allow you to get really close without any proximity, so a decent lavalier would work really well as long as you have the right sensitivity.